# plpgsql Extension not updating after replacing with updated sql & control files in postgres extension directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

So I have a custom plpgsql extension that I installed in `/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension` that works properly.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to update the extension by replacing the `test_ext--1.0.sql` & `test_ext.control` files with updated ones- `test_ext--1.1.sql`.

I've updated the control file to display version 1.1.

test_ext.control

```
# test_ext extension
comment = 'Test Extension for dummy_schema.'
default_version = '1.1'
relocatable = true
# requires = ‘pg_stat_statements’
# directory = 'extension'
```

My steps where:

1. drop the existing extension
2. replace .SQL & control files
3. `CREATE EXTENSION test_ext SCHEMA dummy_schema;`

After creating the extension, I'm still presented with the old extension rather than the new one.

```
                                        List of installed extensions
     Name     | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                              
--------------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 test_ext     | 1.0     | dummy_schema        | Test Extension for dummy_schema.
 plpgsql      | 1.0     | pg_catalog          | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgres_fdw | 1.0     | dummy_schema        | foreign-data wrapper for remote PostgreSQL servers
 timescaledb  | 2.4.0   | dummy_schema        | Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data
(4 rows)
```

I've ran `ALTER EXTENSION test_ext UPDATE to "1.1";`
but I get an error saying

```
ERROR:  extension "test_ext" has no update path from version "1.0" to version "1.1"
```

I've even tried rebooting postgres service after extension install only to get same results.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Dropping the extension and creating it again after changing the control file works fine for me.  But it isn't clear how you "replace" the 'test_ext--1.0.sql' file, as the new one has a different name it isn't really a replacement.

Comment: So I replace it by deleting `test_ext--1.0sql` with a new `test_ext--1.1.sql`.
Are you saying I have to keep the same SQL file name?

Comment: There is no reason to delete the 1.0.sql file, you just add the 1.1.sql file.  You *can* delete it, there just isn't any reason to.